# Installing flutter app in real phone makes ADB exit with code 1

Tags: android, flutter

When using flutter install to install my app on my phone I get this error:

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\Joaom\OneDrive\Documentos\kanyerest_flutter\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed  
to extract native libraries, res=-113]
Install failed
```

However, when using flutter run it installs the app and it all goes ok even though it takes a lot more time, is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: What phone do you use and how do you try to install the app (what commands do you run)?

Comment: I use flutter run

Answer (score 0):

Try  this instead,

- Maybe your device/emulator's storage is full. Try deleting some apps or similar to free up storage.

**Or**

- Invalid package name . for example using capital letter in package name. use this to change package name in flutter as bellow:

  Change the package name in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

  ```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="your.package.name">
  ```

  Also in your `build.gradle` file inside app folder

  ```
   defaultConfig {
     applicationId "your.package.name"
     minSdkVersion 16
     targetSdkVersion 27
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
     testInstrumentationRunner"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  ```

Comment: I have already checked and the phone has enough storage so that is not the problem.
The package name is also correct in all of the files that you mentioned. It is "com.example.sparesmobile" which is fine right?
I really can't tell where the problem is.

Comment: Can you provide project level builde.grade of your app ?

Comment: I placed it as an asnwer to my question. It was too big to add here.

Comment: Please check Is everything is right in your app level build.gradle file such as I already mentioned in answer,  and use "flutter clean " command before running project. run it as usual by "flutter run " while device connected this solve for me try this will work .

Answer (score 0):

@K Michelle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```